# how fill all columns when I use filter function?

Tags: pyspark

I have many columns with true and false value. I wanna make a new column with value 1 if 2 columns are true and 0 otherwise.

```
col1    col2     col3
true    false     true
true     true      true
false    true       false
```

output: filter data if col1 and col2 are true:   `df.filter((df.col(col1)==true) & (df.col(col2)==true))`

```
col1    col2     col3          R
true    false     true         0
true     true      false        1 
false    true       false      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were not explicit if true/false in your df are strings or not. Anyway, higher order functions should make your life easier.

Start here if the true/false values in your df are strings

```
 df=reduce(lambda df,c: df.withColumn(c, df[c].cast('boolean')), df.columns, df)
```

Solution

```
   df =(df.withColumn('R', array([c for c in df.columns]))#Array all the columns
     
     #First transform the booleans into integers
     #Follow that by adding the integers in the array
     #Check if the result above is more than two. That will give you a boolean 
     #Cast the boolean to integer
     .withColumn('R',expr("cast (reduce(transform(R,x->cast(x as integer)),0,(c,i)->c+i)>2 as integer)"))
 
).show()

+-----+-----+-----+---+
| col1| col2| col3|  R|
+-----+-----+-----+---+
| true|false| true|  0|
| true| true| true|  1|
|false| true|false|  0|
+-----+-----+-----+---+
```